# Pandas can't find column when created following solution to SettingWithCopyWarning

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following operation over a Pandas DataFrame in my Python script:

```
a['tier_diff'] = a['tier_rate'].diff()
discontinuity = a.loc[a['tier_diff'] > 1]
```

which causes the following warning message:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning:
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas) aiming to avoid it, getting the code like this:

```
a.loc['tier_diff'] = a['tier_rate'].diff()
discontinuity = a.loc[a['tier_diff'] > 1]
```

but now I get this error: `KeyError: 'tier_diff'`

Can't find what I missed applying the answer

Comment: minus 1, no traceback, no example data, wrongly followed answer

Comment: discontinuity = a.loc[a['tier_diff'] > 1].copy()

Comment: `a['tier_diff'] = a['tier_rate'].diff()` is the problem. Your `a` is a slice of a bigger dataframe, and you can't just modify `a`. so `discontinuity = a.assign(tier_diff=lambda x: x['tier_rate'].diff())` helps as `assign` works on a copy.